# Blazor get div position / coordinates

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm creating a popup component and I want this to be movable. I can move it using the top / left style, but for now they are init to `top:0;left:0;` and so the popup appear on the top left corner of the page. I'm looking to make it appear on the center of the page and then get the Top Left coordinates of my div in ordor to manage properly my calcul after.

here is what I have now:

```
<div class="child-window" draggable="true" style="position:absolute; top: @(offsetY)px; left: @(offsetX)px; border-color: black;" @ondragend="OnDragEnd" @ondragstart="OnDragStart">
   <div class="cw-content">
      @Content
   </div>
</div>

@code {
   private double startX, startY, offsetX, offsetY;

   protected override void OnInitialized() {
        base.OnInitialized();
        ResetStartPosition();
    }

   private void ResetStartPosition() {
        //Set offsetX & offsetY to the top left div position
    }

   private void OnDragStart(DragEventArgs args) {
        startX = args.ClientX;
        startY = args.ClientY;
    }

    private void OnDragEnd(DragEventArgs args) {
        offsetX += args.ClientX - startX;
        offsetY += args.ClientY - startY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Blazor Client Side?

Comment: Yes it is Client Side But this component is placed inside my Razor Class Library @DanielW.

Comment: I think this should help: [https://blazor.tips/blazor-how-to-ready-window-dimensions/](https://blazor.tips/blazor-how-to-ready-window-dimensions/)

Comment: It's a shame we still need to use js interops.

Comment: Supposedly this will be fixed very soon: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8241

Comment: @yToxide Is this meant to be draggable or just animate from centre to a position relative to the div?

Comment: The objectiv is to be draggable after

Answer (score 13):

At the moment it is possible with JS only

```cs
public class BoundingClientRect
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Right { get; set; }
    public double Bottom { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
}

private async Task OnElementClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<BoundingClientRect>("MyDOMGetBoundingClientRect", MyElementReference);

    var x = (int) (e.ClientX - result.Left);
    var y = (int) (e.ClientY - result.Top);
   
   // now you can work with the position relative to the element.
}
```

and

```html
<script> MyDOMGetBoundingClientRect = (element, parm) => { return element.getBoundingClientRect(); }; </script>
```

Comment: I tried this but get:
Unhandled exception rendering component: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: To clarify: I called the JS from OnAfterRenderAsync. 
I need to get the dimensions right after the div is rendered to pass in to a contained BECanvas to calculate how to dynamically scale a drawing to fit. I am especially concerned that I can redraw it to fit when the page scales down to fit on a printed page.

Comment: Have you checked that the element reference is populated?

Comment: I assume that it is not which is causing this error. Any advice to determine what if anything it is set to? Regardless, since I am following the above pattern why would it not be set?

Comment: the error message you get basically says that the object you are calling getBoundingClientRect() on is not an HTML element, so it doesn't find that function. Maybe you are passing a reference to a Blazor component instead of a reference to an html element (both are denoted with @ref) ? Or maybe you need to wait until the reference is populated. Get your element reference in OnAfterRender because before that it will be null.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me with this. The element was a <div> and I did make sure to wait until OnAfterRender to get the reference. I tried to think of every possible reason but couldn't think of any.

Comment: Passing the reference around is problematic.  I finally got it to work by passing the element Id and then had the Javascript find it:  <script>MyDOMGetBoundingClientRect = (elementId) => { return document.getElementById(elementId).getBoundingClientRect(); }; </script>

Comment: Why is a wrapper for this needed can't you just invoke "getBoundingClientRect" directly?

Comment: @Konrad, I am not aware of a method to directly calling methods of DOM nodes from C#. Let me know if you know one