# Blazor selection dragging without javascript (razor syntax)

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, multiple-select

Simplifying the problem i need to select many buttons when i drag , im working with blazor server side so I'm trying to do it using the mousedown event(maybe i have to use mouseover instead) but i only can select the first one.
My question is , can i do what i need without using javascript(with razor syntax and c#), this is my razor code:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Multiple selection example</h1>



@foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
{
    <button disabled="@btn.selected"
            @onclick="(e) => SelectOne(e, btn)"
            @onmouseup="(e) => Over(e, btn)">
        button id @btn.number
    </button>
}


@code{

public List<Button> buttonList = new() {
    new Button() { number = 1 },
    new Button() { number = 2 },
    new Button() { number = 3 },
    new Button() { number = 4 },
    new Button() { number = 5 }
};



public void SelectOne(MouseEventArgs e, Button btn)
{

    btn.selected = !btn.selected;

}
public void Over(MouseEventArgs e, Button btn) {
    if (e.CtrlKey)
    {
        btn.selected = !btn.selected;
    }

}



public class Button
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; } = false;

}
```

}

So when i "mouseover" over the buttons i have to "select" them.

Comment: I can see that you're trying to change the disabled status on several button at once.  However I think only one input can have the focus at any one time, and trigger one button event.

Comment: Yeah but maybe there is a way to fire the event for each button when i drag down 
@MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this directly in Blazor.  As is normally the case, it's not impossible, but you will need a JS library to handle picking up which buttons you have highlighted with your mouse event and then pass the list through Blazor JSInterop to a method that effects the changes and raises a StateHasChanged event on the page.

Comment: Sure i think you are right perhaps i need js. With parts of your ideas "almost" get it but i dont think the solution can approach more,  i put it on an answer check it !

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis at last i get the solution , check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get the solution , it can be done without any js.

```
@page "/"
<h1>Multiple selection example</h1>



@foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
{
    <button disabled="@btn.selected"
            @onclick="(e) => SelectOne(e, btn)"
            @onmouseover="(e) => Over(e, btn)"
            style="border-block-color:@btn.bordercolor"
            >
        button id @btn.number
    </button>
}


<button @onclick="() => this.multipleSelection = false">Disable multiselection</button>
<button @onclick="() => this.multipleSelection = true">multiselection</button>



@code{
    public bool multipleSelection = false;
    public List<Button> buttonList = new()
    {
        new Button() { number = 1 },
        new Button() { number = 2 },
        new Button() { number = 3 },
        new Button() { number = 4 },
        new Button() { number = 5 }
    };



    public void SelectOne(MouseEventArgs e, Button btn) {
        if (!multipleSelection) btn.select();
        if (this.multipleSelection && buttonList.All(x => x.bordercolor == "none"))
        {

            btn.bordercolor = "coral";
            return;

        }
        if (this.multipleSelection && buttonList.Any(x => x.bordercolor != "none"))
        {

            this.multipleSelection = false;

            this.buttonList.Where(X => X.bordercolor != "none").ToList().ForEach(X => X.select());
            this.buttonList.ForEach(x => x.bordercolor = "none");


        }



    }
    public void Over(MouseEventArgs e, Button btn)
    {


        if (this.multipleSelection && buttonList.Any(x => x.bordercolor != "none"))
        {
            btn.bordercolor = "coral";
        }

    }



    public class Button
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; } = false;
        public bool clicked { get; set; } = false;
        public bool hovered { get; set; } = false;
        public string bordercolor = "none";
        public void select() => selected = !selected;
    }


}
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want to multi select some stuff you normally just Ctrl-LeftClick on the items. Are you talking about trying to drag a selection area over some buttons? To detect if the user is pressing Ctrl with the mouse down, just look at the MouseEventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your mousedown handler to include the MouseEventArgs e parameter.

Check e for the CtrlKey property to toggle it's multiselection status as per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.mouseeventargs?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I pass the mouse event args , then i check Ctrlkey righ, and then you suggest to do a method for multilection status am I wrong? @Frank

Comment: @hesolar I am not sure why you are asking. You want to multiselect buttons so just set the button to selected if the Ctrl key is being pressed.

Comment: Im trying what you propose but im not getting the result, maybe im doing wrong , ¿Can you make a minimal example with your solution?  I think that the right event to do what i need maybe is mouseover but im not sure. Thanks.

Comment: Post a new question with your code.

Comment: OK I am not clear what you are trying to do. So the way I understood was that a) on button click you want to select one and deselect all others, b) on button click with Ctrl you want to select that one and leave others selected (enable). Is this correct? What do you mean by "drag down"

Comment: @hesolar if you are trying to work out if boxes fall within a rectangle, by trying to draw over them for example, you will need to call JS to get bounding rectangles https://stackoverflow.com/a/64554452/12285843

Comment: Finally i get it @Frank